# Exception when inflating a layout containing fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout-inflater

I'm developing a [colour wheel app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dobbo.colour) for fun.  Version 0.5 has a palette made up of four fragments, one for each of the possible colour targets on the colour wheel.  The fragments' UI elements are then hidden or shown depending upon the mode of the colour wheel.  "Monochromatic" mode needs only one of the fragments, where as "Accented Anaogic" needs all four.  This works find as the fragments are built and displayed as part of the `onCreate()` method, and are never touched thereafter.

For the next version to improve the layout I have designed four "include" XML layout files, one using only one instance of the fragment, one using two, and so on.  The master XML layout file now has a `FrameLayout` as the point where I replace the appropriate "include" XML layout file when the mode is changed.

Here is the code fragment that performs the change:

```
private void changeLayout(int layoutID) {
    FragmentManager fMgr = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fMgr.beginTransaction();

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.paletteContainer);
    frame.removeAllViews();

    View view = inflater.inflate(layoutID, frame, false);
    frame.addView(view);
    transaction.commit();

    pFrag = (SwatchFragment.Primary) fMgr.findFragmentById(R.id.base);
    a1Frag = (SwatchFragment.FirstAlternate) fMgr.findFragmentById(R.id.alternate1);
    a2Frag = (SwatchFragment.SecondAlternate) fMgr.findFragmentById(R.id.alternate2);
    cFrag = (SwatchFragment.Complementary) fMgr.findFragmentById(R.id.complementary);    
}
```

It exceptions as given below because one or more of the fragments are being reused.  So what is the correct method for replacing part of the UI which contains fragments?

```
E/WheelActivityandroid.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class Navigation item selected: pos=1, id=0x00000001
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) ~[na:0.0]
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) ~[na:0.0]
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) ~[na:0.0]
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) ~[na:0.0]
        at org.dobbo.colour.activity.WheelActivity.changeLayout(WheelActivity.java:321) ~[na:0.0]
        at org.dobbo.colour.activity.WheelActivity.setMode(WheelActivity.java:307) ~[na:0.0]
        at org.dobbo.colour.activity.WheelActivity.onNavigationItemSelected(WheelActivity.java:181) ~[na:0.0]
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$1.onItemSelected(ActionBarView.java:148) ~[na:0.0]
        at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:892) ~[na:0.0]
        at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:49) ~[na:0.0]
        at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:860) ~[na:0.0]
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) ~[na:0.0]
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) ~[na:0.0]
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) ~[na:0.0]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039) ~[na:0.0]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) ~[na:0.0]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) ~[na:0.0]
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) ~[na:0.0]
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) ~[na:0.0]
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) ~[na:0.0]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #11: Duplicate id 0x7f0a000b, tag null, or parent id 0x7f0a0010 with anoth
er fragment for org.dobbo.colour.fragment.SwatchFragment$Primary
        at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4722) ~[na:0.0]
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680) ~[na:0.0]
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

> It exceptions as given below because one or more of the fragments are
>   being reused

Yes, the exception comes from inflating the new layout which has fragments with the same ids(most likely) as fragments that are already in the layout. To avoid this you have several options, for example:

You could use the `FragmentManager` to find the current present fragments and remove them from the layout before inflating the new layout with fragments. For example, if you currently have the layout with just one fragment and you want to inflate the layout with two fragments then you would first remove the fragment present in both layouts:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1)).commit();
getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
mContainer.removeAllViews();
// inflate thew new layout
```

But if I were in your situation I wouldn't use that(mainly because you're messing with static fragments, which you shouldn't do). Now, I don't know how you'll be placing those fragments but it would make a lot more sense(and could save you from other fragment related problems in the future) to have a master layout which will hold placeholder containers(simple `FrameLayouts`) for each of those fragments(all the fragments will be created in the `onCreate` method so you avoid reinstatiating them each time the user changes the layout). This way all you would have to do at runtime is hiding the desired fragments and, if necessary, modifying the parameters of the wrapper containers. With this you'll also get free fragment management(maintaining the fragment state will also be much easy) if the activity will face a configuration destruction(like when rotating the phone).

Comment: I would first like to thank @Luksporg for pointing out the static nature of fragments.  His suggestion for a solution wasn't appropriate for my app.  My vision of the layout was dynamic in nature, and therefore Fragments were not the way to go.  I refacted the fragments into views which solved my issue.  However, my thinking now is that wish to return to fragments and use a custom layout to transition between the various display modes.

Comment: @Dobbo *My vision of the layout was dynamic in nature, and therefore Fragments were not the way to go.* - I think you misunderstood the purpose of the `Fragment` framework. Fragments are not just(or) view wrappers/containers. They were introduced to act as a reusable behavior unit which could be handled much better by the developer. If the layout is dynamic by nature you could use fragments, not to mention, with them, you could provide a better user experience on a larger screen like one of a tablet.

Comment: @Dobbo I've made a little sample which changes randomly 4 layouts, with each of those four layouts containing some of the 4 fragments. You can find it here https://gist.github.com/4362865 . You could also have a look at nested fragments. If that doesn't help, then maybe I'm misunderstanding your question and I will delete my answer.